# Looking for a way to use Pywinauto on Win x64

Tags: python, user-interface, 64-bit, pywinauto

I am using pywinauto for gui automation for quite a long time already. Now I have to move to x64 OS. There seems to be no official version for 64 bit OS. There are clones which claim they support 64, but in practice they don't.

On installation there are several assertions about wrong win structures size. If commented out, the lib manages to install, but some API doesn't work. E.g. win32functions.GetMenuItemInfo() returns Error 87: wrong parameter. This API depends on struct MENUITEMINFOW (which size initially didn't pass the assertion).

Does anybody know how to handle this situation?
Is there a pure pywinauto version to work without additional patches?

And finally, if no answer, is there a powerful Python lib you may suggest for gui automation? With a support of 64 bit?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of windows? I am on Win7x64 and didn't get any errors -- however, I'm using it with a stand-alone patch vs setup.py; which may be why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download this: [pywinauto/pywinauto](https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto), then install by `python.exe setup.py install`

Answer (score 1):

Azurin, you always can use python32bit + pywinauto on your x64 OS. If you realy need python64 you also can use py2exe to compile a test in .exe and use it everywhere, even on OSes where python is not installed. :)

Comment: That's right. You must use Python 32 on 64bit OS to run pywinauto, otherwise you will meet lots of problems.

Answer (score 0):

I only recently learned about `pywinauto` and had no trouble running

```
pip install pywinauto
```

on Win10 64bit. So your problem seems to have been resolved - after ≤ 4 years.

Comment: I am trying to figure out whether I use pywinauto vs pyautogui vs autopy vs sikuli? all of them run on windows... Wondering why you chose pywinauto?

Answer (score -2):

`win32structure.py`

1. ensure `HANDLE` is `c_void_p`
2. redefine other handles like `HBITMAP` to `HANDLE`
3. ensure pointers are pointers and not long